# How do I close a code review with changeset that has been depricated?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, changeset, tfs-code-review

I use Visual Studio 2017, tfs 2017.

I sent a code review on a changeset few months back and forgot to close it. The branch has now been depricated, and so the changeset is gone.

My review now looks like this

[image]

**with no visible/usual way to Close/Abandon it**

[image]

**Is there a way to close reviews with no changesets like this one?**
Its very annoying to see in hanging around there !

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I close a code review with changeset that has been depricated?

As we know, the code review is a work item. You can try to delete the incorrect code review work item by using witadmin destroywi command.

To delete the single code review work item, simply enter the ID as shown:

```
witadmin destroywi /collection:http://TFSServerName:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /id:xx
```

It will cleanup the paper trail in TFS by deleting the useless code review work item, the association with changeset will also be released.

Check the [Remove work items permanently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/remove-work-items-permanently?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ill check this and get back to you !

Comment: Can i update in a few days ? it says i need to install VS community - I need to get permission for this and also it says i " must be a member of the Project Administrators group or be granted explicit permissions to delete or restore work items." -- i need to contact my admin group and get these done.. but i think this is  the solution to this. I'm sorry for the delayed responses, hope you understand.

Comment: @Anu7, Hi, how about this issue now? Have the answer help you to resolve your question?

Comment: this worked thank you ! although i had to get it done by someone with permissions due to lack of permissions :) sorry for the delay though, I was tied up with other works and this needed me to include someone with permissions